# Teradata: UPDATE failed. 7547: Target row updated by multiple source rows

Tags: sql, teradata

`Table1` contains **id, date, flag**.
`Table2` contains **id, date_from, date_to** + some other attributes

Attribute **flag** from `Table1` has to be updated with the following logic:

```
UPDATE t1 from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
SET flag = 1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id and t1.date between t2.date_from and t2.date_to
```

The result is **error 7547: Target row updated by multiple source rows**.
Obviously, the problem is that `Table2` contains intersecting intervals.
How to rewrite query to update the flag in this case?

Comment: This is most likely a data issue, not a code issue

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a *Correlated Subquery*

```
UPDATE t1 
SET flag = 1
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT 1
   FROM Table2 as t2 
   where t1.id = t2.id 
     and t1.date between t2.date_from and t2.date_to
 )
```

Or fix your bad source data :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's when the Update identifies multiple sources (in your example from t2) in the target (t1). Try to make t2.id unique.